# How do I install the latest version of Java on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, java

I want to play on Minecraft servers, I can get on, but can't do anything, I can only play like one day per month. Do I need the latest version of Java or something? I am now using OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime to play Minecraft.
By the way, the happened after I turned off my computer during the upgrade to 14.04 LTS. Before it was all normal. And now I am back to 12.04. Thanks to whoever that helps.

I already got Java 8 but there's a problem, I can't even play Minecraft now! When I go in one of my worlds this comes out:

```
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

Now what? :/

Comment: So, are you 12.04 or 14.04, right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Java version is 8 and available from a Launchpad PPA.

To install Java 8 (OpenJDK 8) open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do I need to uninstall the Java that I currently have?

Comment: @EmilyShan : You can have both versions installed side by side - so it's up to you ... :)

Comment: And I have a question, what's the difference between the up arrow and the check in AskUbuntu?

Comment: Ohhh, ok, thanks. I will see if it works for me(If I can play Minecraft successfully), I'll check right away :)

Comment: And another question, why does the Java 8 looks different(The icon) then 6 and 7? 6 and 7 are like, a penguin type of thingy, and 8 is like the java in Windows :/ Just curious like always

Comment: I'm so nervous my Minecraft is loading I'm putting so much hope on it!

Comment: Yeahh thanks a lot for the commands! And guess what... My Minecraft froze and, I had to restart my computer and, I was uploading a video and, it already finished 70% and, now, I HAVE TO START OVER AGAIN :cries:

Comment: OH NEVER MIND I LOVE YOUTUBE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! My video just countinued uploading so, OH YEAH! lol sorry I'm being very annoying it's just that I talk a lot I can't stop myself!

Comment: (Last comment, sorry for being so annoying) So far I can play 1 game on the server, thanks a lot!!! I'll try out other servers :D really thanks a lot! It's like that you saved my life Minecraft means so much to me! (Eh, I'm crazy ik) Even though I just forgot the difference between the arrow and the check but I did both because you really helped me out A LOT! (I'll check back that comment right now lol). Is there a way like, to "follow" or somthing on AskUbuntu? If so I would love to follow you!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for everything and sorry for being annoying!